# Spring-Boot Camel JPA auto configuration

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, apache-camel

there are a lot of examples of camel and spring dealing with JPA, but I would prefer spring boot autoconfigured data source instead of XML or configuration classes.

However even with

```
spring:

  datasource:

      url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/fooBarBaz

      username: fooBarBaz

      password: fooBarBaz

  jpa:

    hibernate:

      ddl-auto: update

      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

set up

The data source is not picked up:

`No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as auto wire candidate for this dependency.`

Comment: You need to have a Spring bean that is attempting to resolve a datasource before Spring boot will create it

Comment: check this example code, let me know if it helped
https://github.com/RakeshBhat/rb-springcamelmybatis/

its using mybatis, but you will get an idea. You didn't mention are using Datasource from camel level or spring level . If spring level, data-source will be auto-configured for you. If at camel route level, you will need to configure the component. The code is mybatis component in above link.